# Where to find pets for the ranger?

Tags: guild-wars-2

You need to find a juvenile $ANIMAL and charm it. Can anyone provide information about where to find those for the various types of pets?

Do juvenile animals grow up or do they stay this way?

Comment: they're literally everywhere....

Comment: Yeah, this might be a little too broad. [Here](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Pet#Families_and_species) is a list of ranger pets, and if you click on them, it tells you where to find them.

Comment: The "Juvenile" is just the adjective on the friendly NPC animal that tells you it's a potential pet (if you don't already have one of it). They do seem a smaller size than the non-juvenile ones you fight, and they don't change in size after the capture, though you can rename it to something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can find charmable pets all over the game. For locations of each animal, I recommend checking out that animal's page on Guild Wars Wiki. http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Pet#Families_and_species is a good place to start.

"Juvenile" is just the starting tier for each pet, which helps you recognize that that animal can be charmed.

Comment: Do hunt around, I've found the locations of animals to be different  to the wiki, such as, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82602/where-to-find-a-juvenile-shark

Comment: Please add any new locations where you find them to the wiki. That's the beauty of anyone being able to edit it.