# Where to find a Juvenile Shark?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have Shark listed in my pet list, but I can't find it anywhere to tame it. Has anyone found one yet and can you tell me where you found it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharks?

[image]

According to the [Guild Wars 2 Wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Juvenile_Shark), you can find juvenile sharks in the Kessex Hills, specifically, at Viathan Lake and Viathan's Arm. I also found one floating above the Lair of the Seawitch.

[image]

Comment: I saw one in Viathan Lake swimming around just outside the entrance to the Blood Witch's lair.

Comment: I'll go check that out tonight. Being a Norn I haven't ventured over to the Human area's much. Everything is too small and I swear to God if I hit my head on something again, I'll turn into a Bearform and do something terrible. Don't even go there with Rata Sum.

Comment: Found in the bottom right hand corner of Viathans Arm.