# Best role specific pets for Ranger?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Following on from, [this question about sharks!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82602/where-to-find-a-juvenile-shark/82617).

What pets do Rangers mostly use for the various roles in game?

Specifically I'm thinking of things such as,

- Tanking, whist you are ranged - *Bears?*
- Damage, if you are melee or need dmg support - *Devourers?*
- Underwater
- Conditions - *Spiders?*
- Buffs - *Birds?*

So far, I've just been running with two bears as I mostly use ranged damage. Polar Bear and Arctodus which I've found to be excellent tanks. However I've struggled to keep other pets alive during any fights, and even more so underwater. Currently using Ice Drake & Blue Jellyfish.

I do understand some pets are amphibious, but it would be nice to get some suggestions on pet combos which match an actual underwater environment, as well as some 'Pure Stats' ideas.

Comment: You should also check out the [boars](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Boar_(family)). My guild has found these really helpful for dungeons because they can dig up good environmental weapons.

Comment: Relevant information, http://www.reddit.com/r/Guildwars2/comments/104qf0/the_big_list_of_pets_f2_bugs_notes_and_missed/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Pure tanking:**

You are correct that the bears are the most adept at tanking in this game. Their stats at level 80 is:

- Power    1,374
- Precision    1,374
- Toughness    1,374
- Vitality     4,122

This gives them the highest health of any species of pets out there. In addition the bear is the best tank as they have a skill called Defy Pain which allows them to take no damage for several seconds. They also have a skill called Bite which allows them to regenerate. The bear that is also especially adept at tanking is the **Black Bear**. It has a skill called Enfeebling Roar that allows them to weaken all nearby foes, reducing their damage by 50%.

**Pure Damage:**

Your belief that a devourer would be advantageous in support damage isn't quite right. Their stats at level 80 do not have any advantage in power or precision. Their skills aren't particularly superior in the damage department. In fact it focuses more on defensively maneuvers. The main advantage they have is being ranged. In this case, either you would have to the "tank" which is never a good idea for a ranger or the devourer's range is useless since the enemy would just come straight up to them.

The **Lynx** has precision that is higher than most pets. They also inflict vulnerability which increase the damage the enemy takes and bite which is a burst damage skill. They also inflict two sources of bleeding which stacks intensity and duration. Another species of pet that is adept at pure damage is the Canine family which includes the Alpine Wold, Fern Hound, Krytan Drakehound, and Wolf because they have superior power stats. At level 80, their stats are:

- Power    1,718
- Precision    1,374
- Toughness    2,061
- Vitality     1,718

1,718 Power is the highest power stat for landbound animals.

**Buffs/Support:**

The **Fern Hound** has a skill called Regenerate which regenerates itself and all nearby allies. In addition, its species skills allows it to cripple and knockdown foes.

The **Raven** and **White Raven** are able to grant swiftness to all nearby enemies. In addition they are able to inflict blindness on the enemy.

The **Moa** specie is especially adept at support buffs. Their specie skills include a heal that also heals nearby allies. The **Red Moa** is able to grant fury to all nearby allies which increase their critical chance by 20%. The **Blue Moa** is able to use Protecting Screech which grants protection to nearby allies which reduces the damage they take by 33%.

**Underwater Tank:**

If you want a pure tank underwater pet, the **Armor Fish** is a terrific choice. It has the highest armor rating of all the pets and has above normal vitality. At level 80, their stat is:

- Power    1,030
- Precision    1,374
- Toughness    2,404
- Vitality     2,061

To supplement their tanky stats, they also have a skill to add protection to themselves which decrease the damage they take by 33% and have a heal.

And of course as mentioned earlier, the **Bears** are great at tanking due to their superior health. The bears are Amphibious which allows them in water and on land.

**Underwater Damage:**

If you intend to have a huge underwater damage dealer, there is no better choice than the **Shark**. The sharks at level 80 have the following stats:

- Power    2,404
- Precision    1,374
- Toughness    1,374
- Vitality     1,718

They have the highest power compared to any other pets on land or underwater. They have 3 sources of bleeding which stacks damage and Feeding Frenzy increases their attack speed.

Answer (score 1):

The polar bear has the highest power out of all the bears, and therefore has a somewhat advantage at holding the aggro of the enemy when compairing who they find more of a threat.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your build. I run a condition damage Ranger with some fairly heavy pet support, I have a [Lynx](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Juvenile_Lynx) that deals a huge amount of damage through bleed stacks and critical hits, and an [Arctodus](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Juvenile_Arctodus) for additional stacks of bleed and tanking. These have worked excessively well for me. Same idea underwater, [Shark](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Juvenile_Shark) for bleeds and crits alongside an [Armorfish](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Armorfish) for tanking.

Devourers have a high toughness rating and can be used for tanking, but they tend to be a bit more standoffish because of their ranged behavior and retreating tactics. Spiders can apply poison and other conditions but it isn't as highly damaging as bleed, nor do they have a buffed precision stat.