# How do I swap my primary pet when I only have two?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am trying to swap over my default aquatic pet, but as I only have two I don't seem to be able to. Currently my primary aquatic pet is a Jungle Stalker and my secondary pet is an Armour Fish:

[image: my pets]

This means that whenever I go into the water, for the first time after logging in, the pet that I have out will swap from my Spider (primary land pet) to the Jungle Stalker (primary aquatic pet). I know that I can swap these over using the 'swap pet' facility (<kbd>F4</kbd>) but how do I *permanently* swap these over so I don't have to do this?

When I click on the up arrow, both of the pets I have available are coloured in;

[image: changing pets]

However, selecting the Armour Fish in the primary slot causes no action, the selection screen simply closes. This works fine on my land pets because I have three pets, so can select *the other pet* and then select the pet I want in the other slot, but as I only have two aquatic pets this isn't an option.

How do I swap my primary pet when I only have two?

Comment: Whoever keeps downvoting every question I ask should at least give me some indication *why* so I can fix it...

Comment: I have seen this screen be glitchy with my ranger. I recommend just getting a couple of pets for both land and water and then trying to mess with the configuration.

Comment: If I find a third aquatic pet, I have no doubt I will be able to swap them over by setting the primary pet to the new pet, the secondary pet to the old pet, and then the primary slot to the fish again, although if I had two fish I would use both of them anyway

Comment: @pixel If a single person is actually downvoting all your questions, it will eventually be caught and reversed.  They have tools for stuff like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear to currently be possible.

The only solution is to simply tame another [aquatic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82602/where-to-find-a-juvenile-shark) or amphibious pet, thus allowing you to rotate the pets to the desired formation.

Comment: Yeah this is what I ended up doing, it's not really a game breaking issue, but obviously something that got overlooked in the design